# How to set up a federated cluster?

Tags: hadoop

I will paste all my configuration below. I have a cluster of 3 computers. Configuration of namenode 1 (impc2361)

`core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>viewfs//ClusterA</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.ClusterA.link./home</name>
    <value>hdfs//impc2361:8021/home</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.ClusterA.link./home1</name>
    <value>hdfs//impc2359:8020/home1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/Downloads/hadoop2/tmpfold</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

`hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>home,home1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.home</name>
    <value>impc2361:8021</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.home</name>
    <value>impc2361:50070</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.home1</name>
    <value>impc2359:8020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.home1</name>
    <value>impc2359:50070</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I have copied the same configurations on the other nodes as well that is namenode2 (impc2359) and datanode (impc2391)

**Problems**

I don't get the web^page of namenode1(impc2361) when I type impc2361.htcitmr:50070 in web url

It throws an error

> HTTP ERROR 404
>   Problem accessing /dfshealth.jsp.
>   Reason: NOT_FOUND

I get a web page of namenode2 (impc2359) when I type impc2359.htcitmr:50070 but i don't find the folder /home1 which was set in core-site.xml

I am not able to do any operations through my terminal on cluster as it throws a error that it is readonly

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /a
```

> mkdir: InternalDir of ViewFileSystem is readonly; operation=mkdirsPath=/a

Please kindly help

Comment: When i execute the command hadoop fs -ls / on any of the nodes it gives me output of two files home and home1

Comment: hadoop fs -ls /

Comment: Found 2 items
-r-xr-xr-x   - hadoop hadoop          0 2017-03-12 17:38 /home
-r-xr-xr-x   - hadoop hadoop          0 2017-03-12 17:38 /home1

Comment: `/a` is not linked to any namenode. Try creating a directory under `/home`!

Comment: I tried creating a directory named home but it is being created as a file